# errors from API gateway revealing internal details of roles and lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-roles

I have an API in the API gateway, backed by a lambda function. Errors e.g. if the lambda function is running with a role not privileged to invoke lambda function are revealed directly in the API response, including the name of the role, the permission it doesn't have, and the name of the lambda function. Any code change in lambda function will not help because the lambda function did not even get invoked.

Questions to "Amazon Q" are either helping me to fix that role permission error, or to diagnose it with CloudWatch. But that is not my question - I just want errors to hide internal details whatever happens.

How do I configure API gateway to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change API Gateway default responses on the APIGW level (as opposed to lambda level) by changing **Gateway responses**. In the API Gateway console, the option you want is in your API => Gateway responses (on the left under your API name, as of 2024 UI) => pick the error code you want (some kind of 500/502/504 I assume) => edit.

Under the **Mapping template**, you will see something like `{"message":"$context.error.messageString"}`. Replace the `"$context.error.messageString"` with whatever you like, e.g. `{"message":"Error! Guess what happened!"}`. Now that string will be returned instead of your application's exceptions.

Relevant docs and semi-relevant question (it assumes your lambda is working, but the info on mapping templates is still relevant to your question):

- [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-gateway-response-using-the-console.html)
- [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40422062/api-gateway-lambda-python-handling-exceptions/40422063#40422063)

Comment: Yes, I see that. But the problem is that when there is a problem with privileges of the underlying lambda function, the API gives out 200 with an error message. So setting any handler for 40x / 50x will not help.

Comment: If the problem is with lambda's privileges, then your initial statement of "editing lambda's code won't help" is wrong, you can just wrap the whole handler in a `try-catch`. If it's with apigw priviliges (it can't invoke lambda), then my solution (editing default response) will help. If none of these are right, something's missing. Can you edit the exact structure of your setup into the question, including the exact error message you are trying to stop displaying in the api response?

Comment: Also, "api gives out 200 with an error" makes me think there is some extra layer there. "Normal" rest apis return appropriate error codes. Is there a graphql or smth similar somewhere in there?

Comment: There are two parts to this, the integration response, and the method response.
If you look in the cloudwatch execution logs, you will get both messages (you may need to turn on insights for this).

If you can add in what those replies look like and just mask / mock the private details, we can certainly help you out a little further! :)